# getResourceAsStream in a static block sometimes returns null

Tags: java, glassfish, classloader, glassfish-3

I have some code that does this at the top of a class:

```
static {
    ...
    mapper.addMappingConfig(ModelRestMapper.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/mycompany/myapp/rest/dozer/mapping/mapping.xml"));
    ...
}
```

This code *sometimes* fails with this exception:

```
[#|2014-05-23T12:21:33.111-0700|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.dozer.loader.xml.MappingStreamReader|_ThreadID=305;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while loading dozer mapping InputStream: [null]
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:117)
    at org.dozer.loader.xml.MappingStreamReader.read(MappingStreamReader.java:50)
    at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.addMapping(DozerBeanMapper.java:247)
    at com.mycompany.commons.objectmapping.Mapper.addMappingConfig(Mapper.java:62)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.rest.dozer.mapping.ModelRestMapper.<clinit>(ModelRestMapper.java:30) //the line I showed you
at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:140)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1057)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1038)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferences(WebappClassLoader.java:1836)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.stop(WebappClassLoader.java:1662)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.preDestroy(WebappClassLoader.java:1631)
at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarClassLoader.preDestroy(EarClassLoader.java:91)
at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.preDestroy(DeploymentContextImpl.java:151)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle$1.actOn(ApplicationLifecycle.java:281)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:465)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
|#]
```

I'd say this happens about once every 10 deploys and it always seems to work the next time I try.  This is a class deployed inside a war and the app server is GlassFish 3.1.2.  The class is nothing special, just a pojo.  When the error happens and I open up the war, I see that xml file exactly where it should be.  This is my JRE:

```
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)
```

Am I not supposed to use code like this in a war?  Why is this happening and how do I prevent it?

Comment: Which JRE are you using in your production environment?

Answer (score 3):

According to the stack trace the exception occurred when the application context is being destroyed. The problem seems to be connected to the fact that the Glassfish's [WebappClassLoader](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.main.web/war-util/3.1.2/org/glassfish/web/loader/WebappClassLoader.java#WebappClassLoader.clearReferences%28%29) by default sets any of the static and final fields of all the loaded classes to `null` as workaround to avoid memory leaks.

That could lead to the (re-)initialization of your class, that is calling the static initialization block that tries to load a resource and fails due to some sort of race condition.

There is a system property `org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES` that control the process of clearing the references ([link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/systemprops.html)). You can try to set to `false` and see what's happened.

Another (better) option is to move the loading of the resource outside of the static initializer block.

Comment: OK I think I'll use the better option.  I'll see if this ever happens again and if it fixes the problem I'll mark yours as the answer.